# How to Allow only Valid Gmail users sign up in my PHP Laravel website?

Tags: php, laravel

I have this my sign up form in my php Laravel site which I think hackers and robots are making unnecessary sign-ups. But now, I want to allow only Valid Gmail users to create an account. I have configured this form but users with unknown mails are able to sign up. I'm a newbie in php Laravel codes. Someone should please help me configure this to achieve the goal. Thanks in advance. See form bellow.

```
 @csrf
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="{{__('Full Name')}}">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="{{__('Username')}}">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="{{__('Gmail')}}">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="tel" name="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="{{__('WhatsApp Number')}}">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" name="gender" class="form-control" placeholder="{{__('Gender')}}">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" name="item" class="form-control" placeholder="{{__('What do you want to buy? Please type in your issues here')}}">
                            </div>
```

Comment: You need to add something to the validation. Where this is located depends on what front-end scaffolding you used

Comment: I think a Captcha is much more effective at blocking robot signups than trying to find out whether a gmail email address exists.

Answer (score 2):

Laravel have great set of [email validation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-email) tools. Here you can find some detail explanation: https://minuteoflaravel.com/validation/laravel-email-validation-be-aware-of-how-you-validate/

I think that will be enough to prevent most "hackers and robots" emails.

If you still want to accept "gmail.com" addresses only, then you can use, again, [laravel ends-with validator](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-ends-with):

```
'email' => ['ends_with:gmail.com', ...]
```

---

If you want to be sure that they are real emails then I suggest you implement [laravel email verification](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/verification)

For more strict verification you can also use some external services like [Mailgun email verification](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/api-email-validation.html#email-validation-verification).

Answer (score 0):

To stop bots from signing up, you can integrate a captcha service like [ReCaptcha](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/about/).
There are multiple packages which can help you reduce the amount of code to be written. Try having a look at [laravel-recaptcha](https://github.com/biscolab/laravel-recaptcha) package on Github.